# 4 wires from box, 3 wire fixture

Tags: electrical, installation

Black, white, green and bare from box

Fixture has black, white green.

Which wire connects to green from fixture?  Green or bare or both?  If only 1, where does other one go?

Comment: Was there anything hooked up there before?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box? Something's weird here if there's both a green and a bare up there...